# Why does the data streamed using the Java client appear as encoded on Apache Pulsar?

Tags: java, apache-pulsar

I'm trying to stream some data from a Java app into an Apache-Pulsar cluster. The issue that I'm facing is that the data appears to be encoded. .e.g. `"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0018l@\u0000\u0000\u0000�@�\u000fV�\u0001\u0000\u00006B\u0000\u0000�@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\t���AUU�A\u0002(2021-10-04T14:00:00Z\u0002H88c8dc24-233c-45f5-b366-85382d7d52c6\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"`
just the parameters that I send as strings are correct apparently.

My producer code is build this way:

```java
PulsarClient client = PulsarClient.builder()
                .serviceUrl(service_url)
                .tlsTrustCertsFilePath("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt")
                .authentication(
                        AuthenticationFactory.token(token)
                )
                .build();

Producer<DavisMessage> producer = client.newProducer(Schema.AVRO(DavisMessage.class))
                .topic(topic)
                .create();

Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(rec.getTimestamp().getTime());
final String formattedtimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
                .format(timestamp);

float lon = Float.parseFloat((prop.getProperty("sensor.longitude")));
float lat = Float.parseFloat((prop.getProperty("sensor.latitude")));
float alt = Float.parseFloat((prop.getProperty("sensor.altitude")));


log.fine("Sending message to Pulsar.");
producer.newMessage().value(DavisMessage.builder()
                .uuid(prop.getProperty("sensor.uuid"))
                .latitude(lat)
                .longitude(lon)
                .altitude(alt)
                .ts(formattedtimestamp)
                .temp_out((float) rec.getOutsideTemperature())
                .temp_in((float) rec.getInsideTemperature())
                .hum_out((short) rec.getOutsideHumidity())
                .hum_in((short) rec.getInsideHumidity())
                .barometer(rec.getBarometer())
                .rain((float) rec.getRainFall())
                .rain_rate((float) rec.getRainRateHigh())
                .wind_avg((float) rec.getWindSpeedAvg())
                .wind_dir((short) rec.getWindDirection())
                .wind_high((float) rec.getWindSpeedHigh())
                .solar((short) rec.getSolarRadiation())
                .uv((float) rec.getUvIndex())
                .build()).send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is encoded with Avro serialization as requested:

```
Schema.AVRO(DavisMessage.class)
```

You can specify the same schema on the consumer to have it automatically deserialized for you.

If you want to use human readable payload, you can use `Schema.JSON(DavisMessage.class)` instead.

Comment: grazie, Matteo!

Comment: in case I'd like to use a JSON schema, should I make further changes to my schema class? I receive the error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.pulsar.client.api.SchemaSerializationException: org.apache.pulsar.shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class nl.tudelft.davisstreaming.DavisMessage and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer`

Comment: The POJO class needs to be serializable through Jackson. In general, you need to have public getters and a no-args constructor.